# Create Bigquery table using edit text to parse date

Tags: google-bigquery

I wish to create a table using edit text. The reason that I don't use auto detect is that my date format is not in the US format and Bigquery doesn't understand it (I'm not sure if it is a bug or I'm missing something). When I use Auto detect, Bigquery reads the date as mm/dd/yyyy while my date format is dd/mm/yyy.

I've tried the below but I'm getting an error

[image]

```
State:string,
New_Existing:string,
PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', Prd_Dt):DATE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use JSON to write your schema using edit text, refer to this [GCP Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#creating_a_json_schema_file). Using your scenario below this is how we applied it to JSON:
[image]

Output:
[image]

However, you can only use the PARSE_DATE function in Bigquery when doing DML statements such as `SELECT` as per this [GCP Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#parse_date).

Comment: Thanks. But it wouldn't work with me since I have to upload the CSV file to Bigquery (or Cloud storage)